# Capture adjacent Cell with condition

Tags: excel-formula

I have values in `A` column and corresponding values in `B` column. I need capture based on `A` column value I need to capture adjacent cell value which has no zeros.

[image]

Comment: Kindly help me Excel Experts.

Comment: try `pivot` , that should help you..

Comment: Hi Praveen, Thanks for the reply. I need a formula to do that. Kindly help  me.

Answer (score 2):

In my below example:

[image]

The formula in `D1` translates to:

```
{=INDEX(B1:B6,SMALL((A1:A6=C1)*(B1:B6>0)*(ROW(B1:B6)),COUNTIF(B1:B6,0)+1))}
```

Notice it's an array formula that you must enter through <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>Enter</kbd>

It will return the first match that isn't zero.